# I typed in my project "ls > new.txt" but i don't you what is the use of "ls > filename"

Tags: unix

If i type unix ls > filename.txt.
what is the meaning of ls >filename.txt
Thanks&Regards,
Bhadram

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Redirection

Comment: ...see also BashFAQ #55, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055

Comment: ...and the appropriate guide chapter, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Redirection

Comment: ...and the appropriate chapter of the man page, http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections

Comment: (Also, why are you typing something when you don't know what it does and why? Making programmatic use of `ls` is an antipattern -- that is to say, a frequent bad practice; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for details).

Answer (score 0):

Output redirection.

The operating system will execute the "ls" command. Instead of using the standard output (showing the output in the terminal), it will redirect the output to the file "filename.txt"

More information on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)